# Grails-Spock: while projecting values in query id doesn't exist

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing, groovy, spock

I have the following code:

```
def result = Channel.withCriteria {
  projections {
    property ('id')
    property ('name')
  }
}
```

While it runs over full project loading, it runs perfectly. 
But when I'm trying to call this code using Spock plugin, which I first creating those objects:

```
def channel1 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 1', network: network, platform: platform).save()
def channel2 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 2', network: network, platform: platform).save()
def channel3 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 3', network: network, platform: platform).save()
def channel4 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 4', network: network, platform: platform).save()
def channel5 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 5', network: network, platform: platform).save()
def channel6 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 6', network: network, platform: platform).save()
```

The hibernate code doesn't retrieves what I need, It only returns the 'name' field without the 'id' field.

How can I solve this issue?

**Spock spec function code:**

```
def "Checking the entities headers list function"(){

setup:
    def platform = new Platform(name: 'Platform Demo').save()
    assert platform.errors.allErrors.size() == 0

    def network = new Network(id: 1, name: 'Net', framesPerSecond: 25, defaultUnit: unit, defaultManuallyUnit: unit).save()
    assert network.errors.allErrors.size() == 0

    def channel1 = new Channel(id:1, name: 'Channel 1', network: network, platform: platform)
    def channel2 = new Channel(id:2, name: 'Channel 2', network: network, platform: platform)
    def channel3 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 3', network: network, platform: platform)
    def channel4 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 4', network: network, platform: platform)
    def channel5 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 5', network: network, platform: platform)
    def channel6 = new Channel(name: 'Channel 6', network: network, platform: platform)
    channel1.save(flush: true)
    channel2.save(flush: true)
    channel3.save(flush: true)
    channel4.save(flush: true)
    channel5.save(flush: true)
    channel6.save(flush: true)
    assert channel1.errors.allErrors.size() == 0
    assert channel2.errors.allErrors.size() == 0
    assert channel3.errors.allErrors.size() == 0
    assert channel4.errors.allErrors.size() == 0
    assert channel5.errors.allErrors.size() == 0
    assert channel6.errors.allErrors.size() == 0

when:
    params.entityName = "Channels"
    controller.entitiesHeadersList()

then:
    ((JSON.parse(controller.response.contentAsString)) as String[]).size() == Channel.list().size()
}
```

Comment: It will be a good idea if you can also add the spock spec to the question.

Comment: Added, please look at the question.

Comment: Nice question Roey Golzarpoor. This code does not give id in unit test but in integration test its give the id as well. Don't know the reason why. I am curious to know why???

Comment: I also tried to run the test by giving id for each object, and it didn't work as well. The grails version is 2.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stick to Integration tests. Unit tests does not support it right now. Plan is to add full support for hibernate from Grails 2.4.1.

Refer [this JIRA issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10452) for more details.

Although, note that `id` is not bindable by default. So

```
new Channel(id:1, name: 'Channel 1', .....
```

will only work if id is defined as [`bindable: true`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html) in domain class.

Comment: Thanks for the information and JIRA issue link. So, hibernate is not playing any role in unit test is the reason for this???

Comment: GORM simulates most of the interactions with in-memory db in unit test cases. Yes, unit tests are deprived of hibernate features.

Comment: I have noticed that if we use the `projections` to get only id we don't get it. But if we fetch all the instances and then `domainInstances*.id` then it gives the ids.

Comment: Well good to know that `grails 2.4.1` support hibernate in unit test. Thanks